# PDF.js Enable Scrolling

Tags: pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I have managed to use pdfjs to load my pdf document. However, it is not scrollable and I have to use next and previous buttons to navigate. How can I make it scrollable? My JS

```
function renderPDF(canvas) {
  let currentPageNum = 1;
 
  // Handle hidi
  const outputScale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  function adjustCanvasSize(viewport) {
    canvas.width = Math.floor(viewport.width * outputScale);
    canvas.height = Math.floor(viewport.height * outputScale);
    canvas.style.width = Math.floor(viewport.width) + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = Math.floor(viewport.height) + 'px';
  }

  const loadingTask = pdfJS.getDocument(canvas.dataset.path);
  (async () => {
    const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
    let page = await pdf.getPage(1);
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    adjustCanvasSize(viewport);
    canvas.classList.add('border', 'border-purple-500', 'rounded');

    const transform = outputScale !== 1 
    ? [outputScale, 0, 0, outputScale, 0, 0] 
    : null;

    let renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      transform,
      viewport,
    };

    page.render(renderContext);

      var totalPagesDiv = document.getElementById('totalPages');
    totalPagesDiv.innerHTML = pdf.numPages;

    async function onPrevPage() {
      if (currentPageNum <= 1) {
        return;
      }
      currentPageNum -= 1;
      page = await pdf.getPage(currentPageNum);
      page.render(renderContext);
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('special');
      myDiv.innerHTML = currentPageNum;
      
      
    }

    async function onNextPage() {
      if (currentPageNum >= pdf.numPages) {
        return;
      }
      currentPageNum += 1;
      page = await pdf.getPage(currentPageNum);
      page.render(renderContext);
      var myDiv = document.getElementById('special');
      myDiv.innerHTML = currentPageNum;
     
    } 

    document.querySelector('.js-next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);
    document.querySelector('.js-prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage)
   
  })();
}


export default {
  mounted() {
    renderPDF(this.el);
  },
  updated() {
    renderPDF(this.el);
  },
};
```

And my html page. Am using elixir liveview but this page is just basic html.

```
<div class="flex bg-white py-2 ">
   <div class="flex ml-8 space-x-2">
      <div>
         <button class="js-prev" type="button">
         PREV
         </button>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button class="js-next" type="button">
         NEXT
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="special" class="">
   <p>1</p></div>
    <div class="flex">
   <p>of</p></div>
   <div id="totalPages" class="flex">
    <p>0</p></div>
</div>

<div class="flex justify-center">
   <canvas
   class="mt-1 "
   phx-hook="PDF"
   id="pdf-canvas"
   data-path={Routes.upload_book_path(@socket, :book, @book_id)}
   >
   </canvas>
</div>
```

I have added buttons i.e next and Previous. But additionally I want it to be scrollable through the pages.

Comment: I am curious on how to make pdfJs-dist 2.14.305 viewer scrollable vertically in a React project. The demo shows it scrolling but no hint on how to enable it.